# Can humans use magic in "The Hollows"?

Tags: magic, the-hollows, kim-harrison

I just read the first part of *The Hollows* series. However, I became confused about several things, foremost of which is whether humans can use magic or not?

In particular, the character Nick is established as human (and accepted as such by the other characters). However, Rachel Morgan keeps worrying that he might be the practitioner of Black Magic. If humans can't use magic, then why the worry? If they can use magic, then what is the difference between witches/warlocks (and the rest of the near-human inderlanders) and humans?

PS:I don't want to hear whether or not Nick is revealed to be Inderlander/part-Inderlander or some other kind of non-human later in the series. I am more interested in the human/inderlander divide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Humans and witches are *definitely* a separate species, and they *can't* interbreed (which will be a plot point in one book). Witch blood has a specific enzyme that is used to invoke certain types of spells - which means that a non-witch could *invoke*, but not create, an existing spell if they had a container of witch blood. Spells can be bound to objects such as charms or talismans, un-invoked.

However, there are [four different types of magic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollows_%28series%29#Magic) - Earth magic, Ley-line magic, Wild (Elven) magic, and Demonic (black) magic.

Earth charms definitely take witch blood to invoke, but Ley-line magic requires a person be either a Witch, Demon, or Human, to draw on the Ley-line.

**Update:** I added Human to the list of those who can draw on Ley-lines, based on a quote I just found in *The Good, the Bad, and the Undead*. However (major spoiler):

> The book describes Rachel believing that both humans and witches can draw on Ley-lines, but then brings up that Humans only acquired the ability after Elves began *interbreeding* with Humans. It's possible that only Humans with Elvish genes can draw power from Ley-lines, I don't know if it was ever definitively explained.

Update 2 - as noted, I was wrong that Humans can *directly* use Demonic magic - I was confusing it with Ley-line magic.

Demonic magic has two aspects, Dealing Directly with Demons (Dangerous), which Humans can do, and casting a Demonic-type spell (a mix of Ley-line and Earth magic, which only Demons can do). These usually require *very* unpleasant ingredients and rituals, and draw on power from the Demon's realm (the *ever-after*). They *also* generate a residue, called *smut*, that sticks on the caster's aura, and is visible to anyone who can see auras - sort of a "hi, I cast illegal spells" glowing neon sign. :)

Making a deal with a Demon, if the summoner winds up owing a long-term favor to the Demon (as opposed to making payment on the spot), means they will also have a demon-mark put somewhere on them, also generally detectable (and frowned upon).

Demonic magic is illegal, and most books of Demonic spells are destroyed when found.

As for some of the other categories:

- Warlocks are just witches with weaker abilities, not a separate species.
- Werewolves *are* humans, who have been infected or cursed.
- Vampires are humans who have been infected with a specific virus.

Comment: Human's can't cast demonic magic, though.  This is a major factor in books 4-6 (and beyond).  Only demons can kindle demon magic, though anyone can prepare the spell.

Comment: @Jeff, yeah, I was just thinking about how to re-edit that, after discovering that it was ley-line magic that Humans use.

Answer (score 2):

John's answer is generally correct, but there's a few specifics that could stand some clarifying.

Humans can use ley-line magic in the Hollows world.  This isn't an ability they got from interbreeding with elves, because the elf/human hybrids are still 'elves'.  Humans who can use ley-line magic don't have to have an interlander somewhere in their ancestry - it can be learned by some.

Humans can also use already-invoked potions or amulets (earth magic).  Their blood won't invoke the spells, but they can benefit from them exactly as a witch can.

It's also possible for humans to summon demons.  The typical requirement for this is the ability to use ley-line magic.  Summoning a demon isn't illegal, but you are responsible for the actions the demon takes - if the demon kills someone at your request, you are a murderer and the demon is the weapon.  Demon magic inflicts 'smut' on your aura (as does any black magic).  This smut is visible to people who view your aura (a skill that requires only rudimentary ley-line abilities to learn) and is visible in any protective circles you create with ley-line magic.  Having smut on your aura is not a crime, though it does raise suspicions.

When you summon a demon, they charge a price for their work.  The price is generally in the form of a demon mark - essentially a marker that shows you owe them a favor.  If you accrue 3 marks to one demon, they own you and can drag you into the Everafter.  Demon marks place smut on your aura (though the smut is removed when the mark is removed).

So the smut you see on Nick's aura doesn't mean he's evil, but it does indicate that he's done things of a questionable nature.  That he can do magic does NOT mean he's an Interlander, though.

Besides, you think he could fool Jenk's nose?

Comment: I wouldn't say that humans can use invoked charms. I would rather put it as humans, like vampires etc. are affected by already invoked charms.

Answer (score 0):

I've read the series twice and here goes:

Some Humans can use magic. They can draw from a Leyline in a general fashion similar to witches, elves and demons, but limited to a specific set list of spells. They are capable of tapping a line because of the elves use of inbreeding due to a curse crafted by demons about 5000 years ago. Basically, the humans capable of tapping a line are descendants (very very very far) of elves to the point where they are still genetically considered humans. They are known in the Inderlander community as Wizards. It's not an official term used by the government.

Like previously noted in the other answers, there are four kinds of magic: Demonic, Earth, Ley line and Wild.

Earth magic is comprised of using plants, animals and living beings, who subconsciously filter out Leyline energy into their chi and mind, to "cook" spells (potions or earth charms). Anybody can cook these spells. Mix the proper ingredients, etc. Although, for the spell to be invoked (which means, activating it), you need 3-5 drops of witch blood. Demons technically can invoke these charms/spells as well, but due to different enzymes in their blood, they are limited to a certain set list of charms. Humans can use these spells, but they NEED to be INVOKED first.

The previous paragraph explains the use of life forms to create spells. Ley line magic is the person creating the spell draws directly from the line instead of using what the life forms have accumulated. It is possible to concentrate Leyline magic into objects (Leyline charm). This type of magic is used by Humans, Witches, Elves and Demons. All with different set lists but few differences.

The last two paragraphs are the two types of magic for Witches. Earth Charms are considered real changes while Leyline charms are considered illusions and a quick invocation.

Demonic magic is a special technique of magic that only demons can invoke (but anyone who can tap a line can use). It's a mixture of both Earth and Leyline magic. It's permanent like an Earth charm with the quickness of a Leyline spell. Very powerful and NOT illegal per say. Black magic is illegal Demon magic is black, but no laws have been made for it since no one "this side of the lines" has the ability to invoke them. And demon texts are not burned when found, they are usually kept under lock-and-key in the restricted sections of university libraries or even government institutions. Humans can use these spells, but they NEED to be INVOKED first.

Wild magic is vague and not well explained in the series (not yet anyways). It demands the capacity of drawing a line. The elves are known to have practiced this kind of magic, but its terribly risky. Unknown if humans can use this type of magic.

Werewolves came into existence when a demon turned into a wolf, had sex with a human, and got her pregnant which made werewolves. They can only mate with another of their kind. Humans cannot be turned (search: The Focus).